# Drawing people along with x and y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw what’s on this picture:

[image]

I would like to add `tikzpeople` instead of the simple drawings that you can see in the original picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=1.5cm}]
\node[alice,label=Alice] (alice) {};
\node[bob,label=Bob, right=of alice] (bob) {};
\node[businessman, label=business man, below=of alice] (bm) {};
\node[priest,label=priest, right=of bm] (priest) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for people see package `tikzpeople`, https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a simple `pic`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/person/.style={code={
 \draw (-0.5,-1) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0.5,-1) (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.25) (0,0.5)
 circle[radius=0.25] (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
 \node[anchor=north] at (0,-1){#1};}},nodes={align=center,font=\sffamily},
 box/.style={draw,thick}]
 \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] (-6,0) node[left]{geared\\ towards women}-- 
 (6,0)node[right]{geared\\ towards men};
 \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] (0,-6) node[below]{funny}
 -- (0,6)node[above]{serious};
 \path (-2,-1) pic[scale=0.6]{person=Jane} (-1,2) pic[scale=0.6]{person=Jo\~ao} 
 (2.5,-3.5) pic[scale=0.6]{person=John} (1,2) pic[scale=0.6]{person=Maria}
 (-0.1,0.2) node[above left,box]{Harry Potter}
 (4,1) node[above,box]{Star Wars} (4,4) node[above,box]{The Shining}
 (2,-1.5) node[above,box]{The Avengers};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I replace the persons with `\usepackage{tikzpeople}`? I tried to use something like `(-3,4) node[dave, label = below:dave]` but it takes the movie name label along with it and does not look good haha

Comment: @naveganTeX `\path (-2,-1) node[alice,label=below:Jane]{}
 (-1,2) node[dave,label=below:Jo\~ao]{}
 (2.5,-3.5) node[bob,label=below:John]{}
 (1,2) node[duck,label=below:Maria]{}
 (-0.1,0.2) node[above left,box]{Harry Potter}
  (4,1) node[above,box]{Star Wars} (4,4) node[above,box]{The Shining}
  (2,-1.5) node[above,box]{The Avengers};` (will be offline for a few hours now)

Answer (score 9):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.append style={align=center},
box/.style={draw, thick, inner sep=2pt}
                    ]
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[<->,ultra thick] (-5,0) node[left]  {Geared\\ towards woman}
                    -- ( 5,0) node[right] {Geared\\ towards man};
\draw[<->,ultra thick] (0,-5) node[below] {Funny}
                    -- (0, 5) node[above] {Serious};
\node[dave,label=below:Dave]    at (3,-2) {};
\node[bob,label=below:Bob]      at (2,3)  {};
\node[alice,label=below:Alice]  at (-1,2)  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like more abstract drawings of people (as shown on image in your question), than you can draw it as small pictures `\pic`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to plot movie names, now

Comment: @naveganTeX, moves you can simply write in rectangles nodes and positioned as nodes with peoples. See edited answer.

Comment: Your forgot to upload the edited answer!